# Data visualization for accepting key=value pairs for test Score/Health charts/graphs/tables

Tags: web-development, data-visualization, graphs, charts, key-value-store

I get automated test reports with two very simple end-of-test text files in `key=value` format that I would like to be able to convert to graphs and tables viewable in a web browser, and not impossible to discern what’s what in its raw file.

> ```
> //// Test Session: test_session_1490903152672 | Test Type: Lite Test  |
> //
> Test_App=subModuleOne_test.exe 
> Test_Function=iAlwaysFail() 
> Test_Iterations=5 
> Test_Failures=5     
> Test_Health=0 %  
> Test_Result=FAILED   
> Retest_Iterations=20 
> Retest_Failures=20 
> Retest_Health=0 %  
> Retest_Result=FAILED   
> Test_Path=C:\tests\subModuleOne_test.exe 
> // 
> Test_App=subModuleOne_test.exe 
> Test_Function=iSometimesFail() 
> Test_Iterations=5 
> Test_Health=100 %  
> Test_Result=PASSED   
> Test_Path=C:\tests\subModuleOne_test.exe 
> //
> ```

My requirements are the following: 
1.  Multicolor graphing generation (pie, bar, table, w/e) based on values/percentages versus max-value/percentage 
2.  Viewable in both web browser and text editor, with emphasis on web browser. Text editor view can be messy so long as it isn’t garbage when viewed directly 
3.  Flexibility for dynamically available `key=value` pairs to `field`s (note how there are different fields available depending on pass/fail behavior); I don't want these to be static, and this part will not be part of stuff like SQL databases. 
4.  Option to export to HTML format for emails and websites 
5.  The ability to get values and update them real-time or at least occasionally polled/event-based for these visualizations from a remote database, either directly or with something like wget or cURL 
6. Rapid adoption-rate. I want to get the basics rolling, not dive into this deeply or for too terribly long

When it comes to specifically more web-development-centric stacks and technologies, I'm fairly fresh-off-the-boat. I've pretty much only used compiled languages, native scripts, and brief encounters with some of the more popular scripting languages like Python and Ruby. I’m not too picky about which language/technology to use. If anything, I wouldn’t mind trying out something wholly new. What would you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest having a play with the combination of [Jupyter](http://jupyter.org/) Notebooks & [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), (you will need [python](https://www.python.org/) installed first for either of these).

These will allow you to read your text file into a data frame and then the doors open to a rich selection of flexible visualisation options which can be output in a number of formats including web, pdf & image based.

- Free, Gratis & Open Sourced
- Lots of online help

Comment: Hi Steve, I went to try Jupyter's Python demo, but their full tutorial 404s out, which is quite worrying in terms of support. Any alternatives to Jupyter, or Jupyter/Pandas that you could recommend as well?

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck - The online demo may have been down, _it is hosted on rackspace_, or you could be behind a firewall that blocks the secure connection. I just tried it from home and it worked fine. I would suggest trying installing it - it is all free so no cost and if you are used to some companies installers you will be amazed how quick it is to get it installed and running.